# MapBox GL JS (WMS Tile) - Add a single layer from different domains

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, wms

Basically I want some of my layer's tiles to use domain A and some tiles will use domain B, and some tiles domain C.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify multiple tile endpoints https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/sources/ in your source

```
"mapbox-streets": {
    "type": "vector",
    "tiles": [
        "http://a.example.com/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf",
        "http://b.example.com/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf"
    ],
    "maxzoom": 14
}
```